# `updatedb` to grab everything possible

Tags: updatedb

`updatedb.findutils` and `updatedb.mlocate` don't seem to grab everything possible. How can they be instructed to include all files?

```bash
$ printf 'locate: %s, smaller than find: %s\n' "$(sudo locate '*' | wc -l | numfmt --grouping)" "$(sudo find / | wc -l | numfmt --grouping)"
locate: 9 348, smaller than find: 14 053
```

`updatedb` was run as root.

Like title suggest, I want to *grab everything possible*. I don't want to limit `locate`, `updatedb` or `find` in its scope.

I can't modify `.conf` files. I rather need a command that work as-is without modifying files

Answer still gives different results

```bash
$ printf 'locate.mlocate: %s, smaller than find: %s\n' "$(sudo updatedb.mlocate --prune-bind-mounts no --prunefs "" --prunenames "" --prunepaths ""; sudo locate.mlocate '*' | wc -l | numfmt --grouping)" "$(sudo find / | wc -l | numfmt --grouping)"
locate.mlocate: 13 598, smaller than find: 14 053
```

```bash
$ printf 'locate.findutils: %s, smaller than find: %s\n' "$(sudo updatedb.findutils --prunepaths="" --prunefs=""; sudo locate.findutils '*' | wc -l | numfmt --grouping)" "$(sudo find / | wc -l | numfmt --grouping)"
locate.findutils: 13 455, smaller than find: 14 053
```

Comment: ... and `locate` runs as the `nobody` user and so is restricted by permissions, unlike, to a large extent, your `sudo find` command which bypasses most restricted permissions.

Comment: @Bib that’s not necessarily the case, on my systems `locate` finds everything (but filters results depending on what the user running `locate` can see).

Comment: @StephenKitt Isn't that what I have said? Except that running as `nobody`, it does not find everything, as it is restricted where it can go by permissions.

Comment: @Bib I thought you meant that `updatedb` runs as `nobody`. `updatedb` *can* be configured to run as `nobody`, but that’s not the case in many default configurations nowadays. `locate` always runs as the user running it, setgid so that it can read the database. On my systems (Debian, RHEL, Fedora) `updatedb` runs as root and `locate` can thus find anything accessible to the user running it, even root.

Comment: @StephenKitt And on opensuse it runs as `nobody`. Vive la difference.

Comment: @aac you’re still capturing too much in your `find /` — please use something like `sudo find / /home -xdev` instead (using whatever mount points have actual file systems on your system).

Comment: I want to capture everything possible, your command is not enough

Comment: Is this a continuation of your previous question, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705651/locate-all-files-possible?

Comment: The question was closed, and the page was suggesting me posting a new one

Comment: What's the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: I need a command that I can easily use on any computer even when I don't have access to .conf file and I need a list of really every files (or non files or anything)

Comment: What’s wrong with `find /` for that use-case?

Comment: I need a database out

Comment: You’re ignoring my comments about `/proc`. Since your list of files includes that, you can never get the same result twice, so the output from `locate '*'` can never match that from `find /`. You’re close enough that you could use `diff` to compare things to see exactly what the differences are.

Comment: I'm aware of that problem. But I'm still not close enough to consider differences only being because of that

Comment: Maybe not, but with a difference of only ~500, you’re close enough to compare the lists of files directly.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo find /` will always find more files than `locate` in sensible configurations, even when `updatedb` is run as root, because `updatedb` is set up to skip many file systems including virtual file systems like `/proc` and `/sys`.

In the `mlocate` version, if you look at `/etc/updatedb.conf`, you’ll see entries instructing `updatedb` to skip specific file names, paths, and file system types; for example:

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /var/lib/os-prober /var/lib/ceph"
PRUNEFS="NFS afs autofs binfmt_misc ceph cgroup cgroup2 cifs coda configfs curlftpfs debugfs devfs devpts devtmpfs ecryptfs ftpfs fuse.ceph fuse.glusterfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse fuse.mfs fuse.rozofs fuse.sshfs fusectl fusesmb hugetlbfs iso9660 lustre lustre_lite mfs mqueue ncpfs nfs nfs4 ocfs ocfs2 proc pstore rpc_pipefs securityfs shfs smbfs sysfs tmpfs tracefs udev udf usbfs"
```

If you want to compare `find /` and `locate '*'`, you should tell `find` exactly which file systems to scan; for example if you have separate `/` and `/home`, use `sudo find / /home -xdev | wc -l`.

If you want `updatedb` to capture more files, you can edit `/etc/updatedb.conf` as necessary, or override the configuration on the command-line:

```
sudo updatedb --prune-bind-mounts no --prunefs "" --prunenames "" --prunepaths ""
```

For `findutils`, similar overrides are possible:

```
sudo updatedb --prunepaths="" --prunefs=""
```

If you don’t want to overwrite the system database, you can specify an output file name using `-o /path/to/file` (`mlocate`) or `--output=/path/to/file` (`findutils`).

You won’t ever be able to get exactly the same results from `updatedb`/`locate` and `find /` with all files; among other issues, since the contents of `/proc` are always changing, you’ll always get variation there between the time you run `updatedb` and the time you run `find`.

Comment: @aac do you really want to catalog `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev` etc.? `/proc` in particular is always changing.

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 Yes